# C++ Why can const X& be modified by function?

Tags: c++

From another post, I test the example regarding `const X& x` in function. This link [What does “const X& x” mean?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/const-correctness#const-ref-nonsense) says "It means x aliases an X object, but you can’t change that X object via x."  But below example shows we can modify X object? Why?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int a = 1;

void DoWork(const int &n)
{
    a = n * 2;  // If n was a reference to a, n will have been doubled
    cout << "n: " << n << endl;

    //f();  // Might change the value of whatever n refers to
}

int main()
{
    DoWork(a);
    cout << "a: " << a << endl;
}
```

Follow up question:
For example, we have a function return const reference, why can it be assigned to non-const reference?

```
const X& tmp = get();
X& other = tmp; //this works, but why? this get rids of const X& in tmp?
```

Comment: What are your expected values of `a` and `n` ?

Comment: "It means x aliases an X object, but you can’t change that X object **via x**." (emphasis mine). This quote itself answers your question.

Comment: `a = n * 2;` - you are assigning directly to `a`, not to `n`, so `const`ness of `n` doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have confusion about const and references. 
Firstly what is reference `

> it's another name(alias) for an object.

About what's written in function parameters means that `n` is a const reference. It means you can't change `a` through `n`.(or in the simple sense,  `n` can't be on the left side of the assignment operator. It also means that n is bounded to the object permanently.

```
n = n+2; // This is an error as n is const and hence you can't use n to modify the object it is pointing.
a = n+2; // here you are not using `n` to modify. So this is ok.
int x = 10 ;
n = x; // error as n is bounded to `a` so it can't be bounded again to any other variable x. You can see `n` is on left which is an error.
```

Now if you do this

```
cout<<a<<"\t"<<n<<endl; // Output 3; (1+2)
```

About follow up question. (Read it carefully)
Let us suppose a general scenario.

```
const int ci = 1024;
int &r2 = ci;  // error: non const reference to a const object
```

The same is the case with your function question. You must be wondering why we can't do such a thing.
See here c1 is const so we can't change it. Now suppose(JUST SUPPOSE) the following code would have been a legal code. Then r2 will be a reference to c1. 
Now, As i stated reference is other name of an object. It means if we do arithmetic on r2 it will be done on ci.
`r = r+2; // it means ci = ci + 2 ;`
but see ci was const(it shouldn't be altered but we altered it.)
So we need to do something like.

```
const int ci = 1024;
const int &r2 = ci;  // error: non-const reference to a const object
```

This ensures that we can't do 
`r = r +2;` which ensures/preserves the constness of ci.

get() is returning const so to preserve it's constness the variable used to receive from function must be const. So, the part which you said is working is an error as per standard, may be it's your compiler extension.

Comment: Thank you. How about the follow up question?

Comment: Let me write that. Read it carefully.

Comment: "`n` can't be on the right side of the assignment operator" - You mean *left* side.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Oops !

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I still did not get it. " the part which you said is working is an error". For example, for a non-const object X type (say., int type), get() return the const int& r2 which points to ci; ```int ci = 1024; const int& r2 = get(); r2 += 1 //this will work, right? b/c ci is NOT const```?

Comment: @coder See indeed c is not const so it can be changed. so const  int &r2 = get() is fine. As you can convert `non-const to const` but now you made r2 a const. right? So as i told. const can't be on LHS. so r2 +=  1; is equal to r2 = r2+1. In which r2 is on Lhs which is again an error.

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that `const X&` essentially means that the compiler imposes restriction that you cannot mutate the value reference *via* the reference (as the page you linked says). The actual *value* referenced by the reference is purely determined at runtime and the compiler cannot infer that you are mutating the value referenced by `x` when it sees the line `a = n * 2;`.

A small change to your code can help what is going on,

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int a = 1;
int b = 1; // new variable

void DoWork(const int &n)
{
    a = n * 2;  // If n was a reference to a, n will have been doubled
    cout << "n: " << n << endl;

    //f();  // Might change the value of whatever n refers to
}

int main()
{
    // Whether `x` in `DoWork` refers to `b` or `a` is purely determined at runtime.
    if (rand() % 2 == 0)
        DoWork(a);
    else
        DoWork(b);

    cout << "a: " << a << endl;
}
```

In other words, the compiler cannot be sure of what values references will point to. In C++, references can even point to invalid memory,

```
int *a = 0;
int &ref = *a;
cout << ref; // runtime error
```

Hope this helps.

Edit: 
Regarding the followup question, what compiler are you using? Any standard compiler would refuse to compile the code.

Comment: Your example of creating an invalid reference - by dereferencing a null pointer via `int &ref = *a;` - gives undefined behaviour.     The compiler is permitted to assume that there is no undefined behaviour, so the onus is on the developer not to cause undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Peter Yes, but the OP asks why the compiler compiled their code which involves modifying the value the const reference *points to* without errors/warnings.